# void SetSomeValue(int i); of instance member function tracing who set that SomeValue member variable using SetSomeValue()

Tags: c++, design-patterns

i was wondering there is any appropriate design pattern available.

my situation is something like below

```
class CMove {
public:
 void SetSpeed(float fSpeed) { m_fSpeed = fSpeed; }
 void update() { /* do somthing with fSpeed */}
 float m_fSpeed;
};

Class CSomeEvent_1 {
 void OnEvent() { m_Move.SetSpeed(10.f);}
 CMove m_Move;
};

Class CSomeCallBack_1 {
 void OnCallback() { m_Move.SetSpeed(20.f);}
 CMove m_Move;
};
```

when the CMove update step, if CMove of m_fspeed got wrong variable that i don't want to.
so i want to find out what object set it false. but there's a lot of different role of instance existing that have CMove class of membervariable.

at first simple way is

```
void SetSpeed(float fSpeed, char* file, int line) { // do log where's calling from }

m_Move.SetSpeed(10.f, __FILE__, __LINE__);
```

i think it's bed

i want to send like below

```
void SetSpeed(SendObject pObj, float fSpeed) { m_latestSettingObj = pObj; m_fSpeed = fSpeed; }
```

is there any appropriate design pattern available?

or any sugguestion will be helpful

thanks. bonhyoung

Comment: Why do you allow invalid state of CMove? You should throw invalid_argument in SetSpeed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to keep track of from where SetSpeed has been called
e.g. CSomeEvent_1 or CSomeCallback_1 and what speed was set.

You are using several CMove instances in your example but in order to keep track you would need some common structure for all the events/callbacks.

One approach would be to have a static list in CMove and use your SetSpeed(SendObject..) member function to keep track of who is calling and what speed was set. The list could be a circular list to avoid overflowing memory - not sure how often SetSpeed is called?

Or do you want to directly detect when an invalid value was set, then *hansmaad*'s suggestion of throwing an exception containing information about the caller would be the better way.